# Eclipse HotKey: how to switch between tabs?

Tags: eclipse, tabs, hotkeys

How can I switch between opened windows in Eclipse? There is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, but it's asking me which one I want, but I want switch it like tabs in browser or window in operating system (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) without file-selection from the list. How to do this easy thing in Eclipse?

I've tried to assign hotkey for events:

- forward
- forward history
- next page

but it doesn't work the way I want.

Comment: Added OS-specific shortcuts in my answer, but you cannot redefine them.

Comment: I have this problem too. I'm on Mac and I have no page up/down keys.

Answer (score 951, accepted):

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (for a list of editor)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (for switching to the next editor through a list)
  You can assign another shortcut to the 'Next Editor' key.

are the two official shortcuts, but they both involve a list being displayed.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> can cycle through editors without displaying a list.

What is interesting with that last set of shortcuts is:
**they are not listed in the Eclipse Keys shortcuts to be defined.**
They may be inherited from the multipage editor, making them an **OS specific shortcut**.

---

Regarding shortcuts on Mac OS (OSX), [Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139010/m-ll) complained in Sept. 2011 to not being able to remap <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>:

> It drives me nuts to not be able to flip through open tabs as I can in pretty much every other tabbed program in OS X (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>).

Well, in March 2012, [Arthur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486930/arthur) replied:

> , I've just downloaded the latest version of Eclipse (3.7+). I've been able to bind "Previous/Next tab" to (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>) when in Editor, which I'm pretty sure I couldn't do before.
>   So I guess they heard you.
>   It works just as you expect, tabs going from left to right and vice-versa, not on a history basis or some nonsense like that.

[Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139010/m-ll) confirms:

> oh wow, selecting **"Editing Java Source" actually worked**!
>   Now, unfortunately this means that I'm SOL if I nav into a non-Java file (JSP, XML, JS, etc.).
>   **The fix for this is to "copy command" for this pair, and select all the "whens" that I want**.
>   So far it's at least working beautifully for Java and JSP files.
>   This is a major PITA to set up, but it's just a one-time thing.

His [exported preferences are available here](https://gist.github.com/2022533) for you to try.
Once imported, you should see, for all the relevant types of document:

[image: Mac Os key bindings]

Comment: On OSX, replace CTRL with CMD for the first two keyboard actions. But you will still need to use CTRL with PgUp or PgDown to cycle through editors.

Another set of useful KB shortcuts I just found while trying out some of the suggestions below: you can use ALT+Up or ALT+Down to move an entire line of code.

Comment: No chance that there's now a way to remap `CTRL+Page Up`/`CTRL+Page Down` in Indigo, is there? It drives me nuts to not be able to flip through open tabs as I can in pretty much every other tabbed program in OS X (`⌘-Left` and `⌘-Right`).

Comment: On an non-extended OSX keyboard: fn+ctrl+up_arrow / down_arrow by default.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL On OS X, I've just downloaded the latest version of Eclipse. I've been able to bind "Previous/Next tab" to (⌘-Left and ⌘-Right) when in Editor, which I'm pretty sure I couldn't do before. So I guess they heard you. It works just as you expect, tabs going from left to right and vice-versa, not on a history basis or some nonsense like that.

Comment: @Arthur I just updated my Indigo installation to 3.7.2 and I still couldn't get this shortcut to work. All it does it move the cursor to the start/end of the line. I don't see an "editor" choice for the "When:" dropdown, so that might be part of the problem. http://i.stack.imgur.com/EXHuZ.png `::frustrating::`

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL ouch... I guess I should have said that I was on Eclipse for [C/C++](http://i.imgur.com/Xt6ZX.png). Sorry, didn't cross my mind. Doesn't it work with "Editing Java Source"? If that can dampen your pain, when I'm at the far right tab, ⌘-Right won't take me to the far left one... Also, I'm getting really annoying "false errors" (errors are displayed but everything compiles perfectly) since the update. Hope you don't get that too!

Comment: @Arthur oh wow, selecting "Editing Java Source" actually worked! Now, unfortunately this means that I'm SOL if I nav into a non-Java file (JSP, XML, JS, etc.). The fix for this is to "copy command" for this pair, and select all the "whens" that I want. So far it's at least working beautifully for Java and JSP files. This is a major PITA to set up, but it's just a one-time thing. Thanks!

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: thank you for the fix for non-java files. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: One more thing: I've now set up [what _should_ be all the necessary hotkeys](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FmAaR.png) (in my Eclipse for JEE installation; YMMV), and exported my key bindings to save others some time: https://gist.github.com/2022533

Comment: Had no idea about Ctrl+PageUp and Ctrl+PageDown. In OS X, you can use Keyboard Maestro to override Eclipse altogether and just make Cmd+Shift+] do Ctrl+PageDown and Cmd+Shift+[ do Ctrl+PageUp.

Comment: This answer is about switching editors. I'd love an answer to the question - about switching /windows/.

Comment: bloody hell... Eclipse is not consistent. i was looking everywhere for those CTLR page up and page Down shortcuts. i love eclipse but what a mess

Comment: I remapped `ctrl-f6` to `ctrl-tab` and `ctrl-e` to `ctrl-p` to be consistent with the rest of the world. It's quite nice :)

Answer (score 195):

If you go to Preferences (e.g. Window→Preferences) and view General→Keys

and then search for “Next Tab” and “Previous Tab”, you can remap them.

[image: Next Tab command in Eclipse Preferences, before rebinding]

Comment: I've added 
"next tab" -> "Ctrl + Tab"
"previous tab" -> "Ctrl + Shift + Tab"
like it is in Firefox

Comment: This is not exactly the right thing. This just cycles through the tabs in the order they appear on the tab bar vs. most recently switched to order.

Comment: Works great, except for the Android layout editor, which seems to absorb/ignore these commands.  It's always something!

Comment: @Hafthor: I am used to Notepad++, so I wanted the Ctrl+Tab to switch between the *last active* tabs/editors. To do this, remove the default Ctrl+F6 from "Next Editor" and Ctrl+Shift+F6 from "Previous Editor" commands and insert Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab for those commands instead. Note that I had to *remove* the old commands for some reason (which I didn't need to do in other cases where I changed keys), but glad that it works now! Also, while playing around, Eclipse (Juno) acted weird and I couldn't switch tabs using any of the usual or changed key combinations, but a restart fixed that.

Comment: I've added "next tab" -> "Ctrl + Tab" "previous tab" -> "Ctrl + Shift + Tab" like it is in Visual Studio

Comment: Excellent.When you are doing the same make sure you dont make any conflicts with assigned keys. I have always been looking for this one and never came across this question(Regrets). Assigned CTRL+Tab and CTRl+Shift+Tab as with Chrome.

Comment: Setting Scheme to Microsoft visual studio is the best choice for whom having .net back ground. You can easily navigate between tabs using Ctrl + tab keys.

Comment: @FriendFX, thanks for your idea! Note that I had to clear the "Binding" of "Toggle Source/Header" (that was "Ctrl+Tab") in order to prevent conflict.

Answer (score 112):

### Switch like Windows in OS (*go to window which last had focus*)

**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>** in Eclipse, like **<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>** (on windows), brings up a list of tabs/windows available (if you keep the **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** / **<kbd>ALT</kbd>** key depressed) and highlights the one you will jump to when you let go of this key. You do not have to select the window. If you want to traverse several tabs at once hold down the **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** button and tap the **<kbd>TAB</kbd>** button. This is identical behaviour to **<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>** on Windows.

In this sense, **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>** in eclipse is the **<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>** analog. Personally, I change these bindings in Eclipse to be like Visual Studio. I.e. **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>** and **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>** and I do it like this:

Window>Preferences>General>Keys

Then set "Next Editor"=**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>** and "Previous Editor"=**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>**. Don't forget to click "Unbind Command" before setting the new binding.

### Switch like browser (*go to tab on the right of current tab*)

This is **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>PageDown</kbd>** to go right, **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>PageUp</kbd>** to go left. Frustratingly, when you get to the end of the list of tabs (say far right hand tab) and then try to go right again Eclipse does not cycle round to the first tab (far left) like most browsers would.

Comment: This is the most under-rated answer in this thread. Especially since Juno changes which tabs are shown to be a pure list and not the recently used editors.

Comment: This works 90% of the time.  It fails if your mouse cursor happens to be where the list of tabs pops up.  Whatever unlucky tab pops up in front of the cursor gets selected.

Comment: Eclipse version 3.6.2 works 100% of the time, wherever the mouse is. It is, after all, Eclipse's natural behaviour re-mapped to different keys! 
Haven't tried ancient Eclipse versions though...

Comment: You don't have to unbind the "Next Editor" command. Just click "Copy Command" and edit the copy and bind it to `CTRL-TAB`.

Comment: It works after eclipse restart for me. Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) I think this answer must be accepted.

Comment: The unbind reminder is key. In eclipse 2019-03, it didn't work until the original command was removed, it seems to no longer support multiple bindings.

Comment: @Robino wrote: "*Eclipse does not cycle round to the first tab*" You can configure Eclipse to do this! *Preferences > General > Appearance*, uncheck *Show most recently used tabs*. See here for [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44959669/452775).

Answer (score 56):

You can use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to go to your previous tab, or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to go to forward. This method is using tab-switching like history, though, so it will go to the previous tab you had open, and forward if you've gone "back" once or more. A bit weird, I know, but it works. You can always "reset" the history by clicking through every tab once.

Comment: Not useful when there are actions recorded in history, such as going to method definition in the same class.

Comment: this used to be useful, for eclipse helios this works as SiN mentioned

Comment: I actually like the behavior where it goes to actions such as going to method definition, it's a useful way to go back and forth when navigating around a lot of files.

Comment: This works great when cycling back and forth between editing windows. I like to split my screen in 2 and the other methods only cycle 1 tab grouping, (except ctrl-F6, but I find that cumbersome).

Answer (score 15):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> is good to use. If you want to switch to next/previous tab, you need to do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, I often use this one. However, when the editor proposes multiples views (for example when you work on a `XML` or `properties` file), it switches between the different views, and you are not able to switch between tabs anymore :(

Comment: "CTRL + F6 is good to use." Does nothing here, on Eclipse Photon in Windows.

Answer (score 15):

- `Right` side move : **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>page Down</kbd>**
- `Left` side move : **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>page Up</kbd>**

**Additional**

- get list of open tabs : **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>**

**Eclipse others Short Cuts**

- Link : http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html
- Pdf :  http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/Keyboard_shortcuts_%283.0%29.pdf

Answer (score 12):

The default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>. You can change it by going to *Window preferences*. I usually change it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the same we use in switching tabs in a browser and other stuff.

Comment: I'm not a down-voter, but I question your ability to map a key binding with Ctrl + Tab together on Windows Vista, using Eclipse Indigo. It's impossble! If I were to press Tab, it would simply change the focus on the buttons and drop-down list.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 Sorry, I'm not aware of this issue with Windows Vista. You can try a different mapping of your choice, though it's  successful in XP.

Answer (score 8):

Shortcut key to back to the previous tab

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> to go back.

Answer (score 7):

> Custom KeyBinding sequence example :  <kbd>CTRL + TAB</kbd>  to switch between visilble Modules or Editors **Forward** direction using Eclipse RCP.

you press <kbd>CTRL + TAB</kbd>  second  time to open
another editor and close previous editor using RCP Eclipse.

```
package rcp_demo.Toolbar;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorReference;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditorInput;

public class Forward_Editor extends AbstractHandler{

    static String Editor_name;  //  Active Editor name store in Temporary 
    static int cnt;             //  close editor count this variable
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();

        UserEditorInput std_input = new UserEditorInput();
        EmployeeEditorInput emp_input=new EmployeeEditorInput();
        ProductEditorInput product_input=new ProductEditorInput();

        IEditorReference[] editors = page.getEditorReferences();

        //Blank Editor Window to execute..
        if(editors.length==0)
        {
            //First time close editor can open Student_Editor
            if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Student_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("EMP>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
            }
            //First time close editor can open Employee_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Employee_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("PRO>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name); 
                } catch (PartInitException e) {e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //First time close editor can open Product_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Product_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                    System.out.println("student Editor open");
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("Close::"+Editor_name);
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //First Time call // empty editors 
            else{
                try {
                    page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                    System.out.println("student Editor open");
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }//End if condition

        //AvtiveEditor(Student_Editor) close to open Employee Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Student_Editor"))
        {
            try {
                //page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.closeEditor(page.getActiveEditor(), true);
                page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("EMP>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Employee_Editor) close to open Product Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Employee_Editor"))
        {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);

                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("PRO>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);

            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Product_Editor) close to open Student Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Product_Editor"))
        {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("stud>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //by default open Student Editor
        else 
        {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("stud_else>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

>Custom KeyBinding sequence example : <kbd> SHIFT + TAB </kbd> to switch between visilble Modules or Editors **Backword** direction using Eclipse RCP.


package rcp_demo.Toolbar;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorReference;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditorInput;

public class Backword_Editor extends AbstractHandler{

    static String Editor_name;   // Active Editor name store in Temporary 
    static int cnt;

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
        //Three object create in EditorInput 
        UserEditorInput std_input = new UserEditorInput();
        EmployeeEditorInput emp_input=new EmployeeEditorInput();
        ProductEditorInput product_input=new ProductEditorInput();

        IEditorReference[] editors = page.getEditorReferences();
        System.out.println("Length : "+editors.length);

        if(editors.length==0)
        {
            //First time close editor can open Student_Editor
            if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Product_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("EMP>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
            //First time close editor can open Employee_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Employee_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("Student>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..student::"+Editor_name);

                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //First time close editor can open Product_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Student_Editor"))
            {
                        try {
                            page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                            cnt=1;
                            Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                            System.out.println("PRO>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);

                        } catch (PartInitException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            } 
            //First Time or empty editors to check this condition
            else{
                try {
                    page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                    System.out.println("product Editor open");
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Product_Editor) close to open Employee Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Product_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("Employee Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Employee_Editor) close to open Student Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Employee_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Emp:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("student Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Student_Editor) close to open Product Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Student_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //by default open Student Editor
        else 
        {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> Custom KeyBinding sequence example :  <kbd>SHIFT + TAB</kbd>  to switch between visilble Modules or Editors **Backword** direction using Eclipse RCP.

```
package rcp_demo.Toolbar;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorReference;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.EmployeeEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.ProductEditorInput;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditor;
import rcp_demo.Editor.UserEditorInput;

public class Backword_Editor extends AbstractHandler{

    static String Editor_name;   // Active Editor name store in Temporary 
    static int cnt;

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
        //Three object create in EditorInput 
        UserEditorInput std_input = new UserEditorInput();
        EmployeeEditorInput emp_input=new EmployeeEditorInput();
        ProductEditorInput product_input=new ProductEditorInput();

        IEditorReference[] editors = page.getEditorReferences();
        System.out.println("Length : "+editors.length);

        if(editors.length==0)
        {
            //First time close editor can open Student_Editor
            if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Product_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("EMP>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
            //First time close editor can open Employee_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Employee_Editor"))
            {
                try {
                    page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                    cnt=1;
                    Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                    System.out.println("Student>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..student::"+Editor_name);

                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //First time close editor can open Product_Editor
            else if(cnt==1 && Editor_name.equals("Student_Editor"))
            {
                        try {
                            page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                            cnt=1;
                            Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                            System.out.println("PRO>>Len:: "+editors.length+"..EDi::"+Editor_name);

                        } catch (PartInitException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            } 
            //First Time or empty editors to check this condition
            else{
                try {
                    page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                    System.out.println("product Editor open");
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Product_Editor) close to open Employee Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Product_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("Employee Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Employee_Editor) close to open Student Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Employee_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Emp:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("student Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //AvtiveEditor(Student_Editor) close to open Product Editor
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Student_Editor"))
        {
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //by default open Student Editor
        else 
        {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                cnt=1;
                Editor_name=page.getActiveEditor().getTitle();
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> Key Sequence

M1 means  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

M2 means <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>

> plugin.xml

---

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
        <command
                defaultHandler="rcp_demo.Toolbar.Forward_Editor"
                id="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.Forward_editor_open_cmd"
                name="Forward_Editor">
        </command>
        <command
                defaultHandler="rcp_demo.Toolbar.Backword_Editor"
                id="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.backwards_editor_open_cmd"
                name="Backword_Editor">
        </command>
    </extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
        <key
                commandId="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.Forward_editor_open_cmd"
                schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
                sequence="M1+TAB">
        </key>  
        <key
                commandId="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.backwards_editor_open_cmd"
                schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
                sequence="M2+TAB">
        </key>              
</extension>
```

Answer (score 6):

3 line AutoHotKey script (on Windows, anyway):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class SWT_Window0
^+Tab::^PgUp
^Tab::^PgDn
```

Put this in your startup folder (save it as *.ahk, must have AutoHotKey installed) and Eclipse tabs will now work like Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Solved!!

Change Scheme to Microsoft Visual Studio

Window>Preferences>General>Keys

Look for Schemes dropdown

My eclipse version:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20120920-0800

Answer (score 3):

Nobody will ever read my answer, but anyway... If you are on Mac OS X you will love multi touch gestures for history navigation in Eclipse: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/eclipsemultitch/

Comment: I read *all* entries [every single day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309) ;) And "Eclipse Multi-Touch" looks nice, so +1. But it seems inactive since 2010. Would it still work with recent Eclipse 4.x like Juno?

Answer (score 2):

On windows if you have a 5 button mouse, you can use forward and back in lieu of <kbd>ALT+Left</kbd> and <kbd>ALT+Right</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Right to left : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>  or  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd>

Left to right : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use the [VI Plugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin.htm), and then you just do :n (and :N) to go between files.

That's what I do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply switch between your current and your previous tab selections, using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> will switch you back and forth. To navigate to a tab further back in your history, you need to use the <kbd>UP</kbd> / <kbd>DOWN</kbd> keys while the Editors window is open. This works with Helios (Eclipse 3.6); not sure if this is true for older versions of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason my Eclipse settings were corrupted so I had to manually edit the file **/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi**

I must have previously set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Browser-like tab switching, and even resetting all key bindings in Eclipse preferences wouldn't get rid of the shortcuts (they were not displayed anywhere either). I opened the above mentioned file and removed the `<bindings>` elements marked with `<tags>type:user</tags>` related to the non-functioning shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the hotkeys in Preferences -> General -> Keys (or just type "keys" into the filter field at the top of the Preferences dialog.

Once the Keys section is selected, find Next Tab and Previous Tab and assign them your own hotkey by clicking in the "Binding" field and then typing your hotkeys.

Hit Apply or OK to finish the process.

Answer (score 1):

I quote VonC response, adding something.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>(<kbd>PgDn</kbd>) to switch between tabs in the current stack (both editors and view)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to switch between tabs in the current stack, using a filtered list
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to switch between editors, no matter which stack
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch between views, no matter which stack

Plus, there is [Bug 206299](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=206299) open to request using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for switching tabs instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>(<kbd>PgDn</kbd>).

- As this would break accessibility, the user should set a preference for this. Perhaps there should be a question in the Welcome Questionnaire during to the Oomph installs.

If not satisfied, you can assign yourself the Key Binding, from *Window > Preferences > General > Keys*.

Answer (score 0):

Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and press <kbd>F6</kbd> until you reached the editor you want, then release. The UI is not as pretty as the window selection, but the functionality is the same.

Answer (score 0):

On a SLES12 machine you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> to navigate between tabs by default. You can always change these keys from Preferences window by browsing through "keys" section under "General" category.
This process is well explained by Victor and VonC above.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I switch between opened windows in Eclipse

CTRL+F7 works here - Eclipse Photon on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, just adding a new binding doesn't seem to work (eclipse 2021-06).

Instead:

- use `Copy Command` to clone `Next Tab`  and `Previous Tab`
- change "When" to `In Windows`
- add your new binding
- `Apply and Close`

[image: screenshot of eclipse key mapping]

@Gillfish mentioned this in a comment on another answer, but i thought its better to surface the solution explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Versions of Eclipse up to 2022-03 used to have <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switch between editors in an LRU order, same as <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> - I believe it was the same functionality. Starting with the 2022 versions, this was no longer the case with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> instead using to move to a different pane (i.e. move from the editor to the bottom pane, or from the bottom pane to the one of the side bars).

In either case, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> isn't shown as a used binding in the Windows->Preferences->General->Keys configuration dialog - it seems to be hard-coded.

It really annoyed me because I'm very used to using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch tabs in a multi-tab application and regardless, it is a much easier shortcut than <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

My solution was to go into the keys configuration dialog and replace the "Quick Switch Editor" shortcut from <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

The "Quick Switch Editor" is basically what I need - press once and quickly release, and you go back to the previously used editor; press once and hold the modifier - you get a menu where you can navigate to a different editor in LRU order.