# Eclipse's Visual Studio Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab Equivalent

Tags: eclipse, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, I always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate between documents. I see that Eclipse has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to navigate between editors, but this isn't nearly the same behavior. The difference being, pressing it once and then again will get you moving back and forth between two files, whereas in VS, it will cause you to navigate forward based on the tab order in the editor. Any ideas on how I can replicate VS's behavior?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332330/eclipse-hotkey-how-to-switch-between-tabs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking at **Keys** in the preferences dialog, there are commands for "Next editor" and "Previous editor", bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>.

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page up</kbd>/<kbd>Page down</kbd>, but that might be specific to Linux because it's the same shortcut in other apps such as Nautilus and Terminal.

Comment: Page up and down were exactly what I needed. Works on Windows too.

Comment: This isn't the exact same behavior.  It simply moves to the "next" document located on the next physical tab.  If you ctrl-tabbed to a document three tabs over and wanted to switch back to the previous document, you can hit ctrl-tab once (in Visual Studio)..but you have to hit ctrl-pgup thrice in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I just set the *Next tab* and *Previous tab* actions under **Preferences** > **General** > **Keys** to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> respectively and it works just fine. Eclipse is highly customizable