# Using Ctrl-tab requires pressing the enter key in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I went into  Window->Preferences->General->Keys in Eclipse to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to "Previous Editor".  At first it worked just like Visual Studio's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>..I can switch the last file I was editing.  Now, for some reason, Eclipse will not switch to the previous file after I release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.  Instead, I have to press Enter after releasing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.  It's very annoying.

Does anyone know how I can have Eclipse switch to the previous file by just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Thanks

Comment: is the same thing happening when you use Ctrl + e, or Ctrl + page up/down? or just with your custom keybind?

Comment: Ctrl+e=yes..Ctrl+pgup/pgdn=no

Answer (score 14):

You're looking for this: [Eclipse's Visual Studio Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751573/eclipses-visual-studio-ctrltab-and-ctrlshifttab-equivalent).

By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> you get the behaviour (I think) you're looking for. On 
`Window`->`Preferences`->`General`->`Keys` you could switch the key binding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: For reference, they command names OP wants are "Next Editor" and "Previous Editor". On CDT the default Ctrl + Tab binding is "Toggle Source/Header".

Answer (score 5):

Go to the .metadata directory in the workspace's folder and open the file `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs` located in `.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings`.

You have in it an option named `STICKY_CYCLE` which must be set to true. Put it to false or simply remove the whole line.

The matching line when exporting the preferences is : `/instance/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/STICKY_CYCLE=false`

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse Juno
Window Menu/Preferences/General
Uncheck "Keep next/previous editor view and prespectives dialog open

fixed for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, and found a solution.

However, the problem was not due to Eclipse, but due to my Caps Lock key settings.  Therefore this solution might not apply to your problem.  Given the frustration I went through to fix this, I would still like to share this with you.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. In the System Settings, under Keyboard Layout, Options..., I had "Caps Lock key behavior" set to "Make Caps Lock an additional Control but keep the Caps_Lock keysym".

When I changed this to "Default" and changed the "Ctrl key position" to "Caps Lock as Ctrl", the problem in Eclipse was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Related to @tijs answer, on Xubuntu 20.20 (and possibly other Ubuntu versions), this problem can appear in combination with keyboard layout settings. I solved it as follows:

First, make sure to un-check: *Preferences > General > Keep next/previous editor view and prespectives dialog open*

Then open system keyboard settings (xfce4-keyboard-settings) *Layout > Change layout option*

My setting for "Change layout option" was "Both Ctrl together". I changed it to none (`-`)

Now, the Next/Previous Editor in Eclipse worked correctly with Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab, (i.e. not requiring pressing Enter).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch tabs using CTRL+TAB key like in chrome
Goto Prefrences -> Keys -> search tab -> then in Next Editor  entry change shortcut to CTRL+TAB

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUWFN.png)

Comment: How is this different from the existing Answers?