# Which eclipse plugin implements Ctrl+PageDown or M1+PageDown

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am learning eclipse plugin development and a great deal of learning can be done by looking at the implementation of an existing builtin plugin itself.
While I was looking for a shortcut to switch between tabs I found this --> [Eclipse HotKey: how to switch between tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332330/eclipse-hotkey-how-to-switch-between-tabs)

However I am not able to search the ***command*** /***key*** binding/ ***Handler*** class that actually implements the Ctrl+PageDown key binding.

Similarly, I was able to find the ***key*** binding and the ***command*** of  of M3+PAGE_DOWN (ALT+PAGE_DOWN) in plugins/org.eclipse.ui_some_version.jar (org.eclipse.ui_3.103.0.v20120705-114351.jar in my case) but not the ***Handler***.

**How can I find these out? Which plugin should I refer to?**

Answer (score 0):

Those commands get handled programatically inside 
    org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.
Good tools for analysing the origin of elements are the "Plug-In Registry" View, the "Plug-In Spy" and Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the handler in org.eclipse.ui.workbench (see class org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart)

The handler is defined programmatically and not declaratively:

```java
public abstract class MultiPageEditorPart extends EditorPart implements IPageChangeProvider {

    private static final String COMMAND_NEXT_SUB_TAB = "org.eclipse.ui.navigate.nextSubTab"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private void initializeSubTabSwitching() {
        IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService) getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);
        service.activateHandler(COMMAND_NEXT_SUB_TAB, new AbstractHandler() {
            // ...
            }
        });
}
```