# Eclipse shortcuts: How to switch between tabs like Chrome, Firefox in Mac OS x?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In Chrome or Firefox, I can switch between tabs using shortcut like: Cmd+1, Cmd+2.

How to using it in Eclipse? Or How to config in Eclipse?

Thanks for reading...

Comment: Perform a better search before post a question... possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332330/eclipse-hotkey-how-to-switch-between-tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can change of open tabs using the hotkey:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>