# Eclipse Shortcut for switching the class-windows

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

since 6 weeks i´m studying WI. Thats somewhere between business management and IT.

We´re using eclipse and i´m looking for a shortcut that allows to switch between the class-windows like alt + tab for Windows.... windows^^.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse HotKey: how to switch between tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332330/eclipse-hotkey-how-to-switch-between-tabs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in tool bar go to Window>Preferences>General>key : change shortcut key as per your use and us can also fine another shortcut for eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same Shortcut.
I changed the class window accidently with a shortcut and then found out, that you can do it with **tab + alt + right/left** instead of alt + tab (changes the windows from Windows :D).
**Make sure** to tab + alt **in a free row where no code is**, as it will push the line to the right, because of the tab button.

Whoever will search for this.
You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use: Alt + Arrow Key Left/Right

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : Ctrl + pg up/ Ctrl + pg dn