# Eclipse editor tab wrap-around

Tags: eclipse

I can switch editors in Eclipse by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PdDown</kbd>.

But when the leftmost editor tab is selected, I cannot switch one more tab to the left and wrap-around to get to the rightmost tab.

How can I make my editor tabs wrap-around?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Show most recently used tabs* setting must be disabled for tabs to wrap-around.

Go to *Preferences* > *General* > *Appearance* and uncheck the *Show most recently used tabs* box.

[image]