# Command to go to previous file in Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse

In visual studio ctrl+tab would bring the previous viewed file back to the foreground.  I can't seem to recreate this simple behavior in any of the obvious eclipse commands, and I am not permitted to install any 3rd party plugins that might add this functionality.

I have found commands that take me through the previous edit locations (which could be mulitple locations per file), that switch to the next and previous file in file tab order, but no command that will take me to the last viewed file.

Is this just not available?

Comment: Look to that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332330/eclipse-hotkey-how-to-switch-between-tabs

Comment: Is Alt+Arrow_Left/Right what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Enter **Ctrl + F6** key .It will take you to last opened file in eclipse.